# Django models relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I build an application where people post ads for sale different things like a cars,apartments, gadgets & etc. I have models with its own special fields for each  item like a : CarModel, ApartmentModel, SmartphoneModel etc...

And I have a model Article : and want to add field *item_of_sale* which can be instance of different models (for example CarModel or ApartmentModel).

```
class Article(models.Model):

author = 
    models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles' )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE )        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    text = models.TextField()

    item_of_sale = # ??????? models.OneToOneField I suppose
```

I try something like this:

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
   ad = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                             related_name='item_of_sale')
   marc = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARC_CHOICES)
   model = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
   .....


class ApartmentModel(models.Model):
   ad = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                             related_name='item_of_sale')
   location= models.CharField(max_length=200 )
   address= models.CharField(max_length=120)
   .....
```

But django does not allow to have more than one model with  related_name="item_of_sale" .

Have you any ideas how I can make database with this kind of relations. Please any help . Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to read up on types of relationships... there aren't only one-to-one... you can use one-to-many or many-to-many... Try reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/django-orm-relationships-cheat-sheet-14433d6cf68c) article or the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/)

Comment: Hope your project will turn out great ^_^

Comment: @Kendoka your first link really helps me .**Polymorphic One to Many Relationship** from ** django-polymorphic package** is what I was looking for. Thank you. If you want add  it as answer  I will check it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

related name is for backward query .relented  name is optional field related need to be unique . your model is very simple you don't need any related name.`define you model with out related name . .